# how to fix css issue with height

Tags: html, css

Here is the code snippet:

```css
/* text types */
h1{font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; font-size: 24px; line-height: 125%;}
h2{font-family: 'Neuton', serif; margin: 5px 0px 10px 0px; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 200; line-height: 120%;}
h3{font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; margin: 8px 0px 2px 0px; font-size: 16px; line-height: 130%; font-weight: 600;}
h4{font-family: 'Neuton', serif; font-size: 16px; margin: 2px 0px 6px 0px; line-height: 120%; font-weight: 200;}
h5{font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; font-size: 12px;}
h6{font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;}

/* links */
a, a:hover, a:visited, a:active{text-decoration: none; outline: none; color: inherit;}
a.underline:hover{text-decoration: underline; color: inherit;}
a.readMore{font-family: 'Raleway', serif; font-size: 15px; margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px; font-weight: 700; color: #428bca;}
.thinner{
 font-weight: 200;
}
.thin{
 font-weight: 300;
}
.normal{
 font-weight: 400;
}
.bold{
 font-weight: 500;
}
.bolder{
 font-weight: 600;
}
.boldest{
 font-weight: 700;
}

.sanserif{
 font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

/* align */
.text-left{
 text-align: left;
}
.text-right{
 text-align: right;
}

/* body */
body, html{
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
.container-page-80{
 width: 80%;
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
}
.container-page-100{
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
}


/* height adj */
.height-100{
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
}
.height-75{
 height: 75%;
 position: absolute;
}
.height-50{
 height: 50%;
 position: absolute;
}
.height-40px{
 height: 40px;
}

/* positions */
.fixed{
 position: fixed;
}
.vert-align-1{
 vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

/* images */
img.main-logo{
 height: 35px;
}

/* inputs */
input[type=text].search-bar{
 outline: none;
 height: 28px;
 padding: 0px 6px;
 width: 93%;
 outline: none;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
 font-size: 15px;
 letter-spacing: 0.5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 opacity: .8;
 -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 -ms-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 transition: all 250ms ease-out;
}
input[type=text].search-bar:focus{
 color: black;
 opacity: 1;
}
input[type=text].search-bar:hover{
 color: black;
 opacity: 1;
}
button.start-selling{
 height: 30px;
 outline: none;
 background: none;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 font-size: 12px;
 color: white;
 padding: 0px 12px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 background-color: #9059b2;
 opacity: .9;
 -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 -ms-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 transition: all 250ms ease-out;
}
button.start-selling:hover{
 opacity: 1;
}
button.sign-in{
 height: 30px;
 outline: none;
 background: none;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 font-size: 12px;
 color: black;
 font-weight: 700;
 padding: 0px 12px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 background-color: none;
 opacity: .9;
 -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 -ms-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 transition: all 250ms ease-out;
}
.puma{
 background-color: red;
}






/*  SECTIONS  */
.section-np{
 clear: both;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col-np {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin: 0% 0 0% 0%;
}
.col-np:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group-np:before,
.group-np:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group-np:after { clear:both;}
.group-np { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }
/*  GRID OF TWELVE  */
.span_12_of_12-np {
 width: 100%;
}

.span_11_of_12-np {
   width: 91.66%;
}
.span_10_of_12-np {
   width: 83.33%;
}

.span_9_of_12-np {
   width: 75%;
}

.span_8_of_12-np {
   width: 66.66%;
}

.span_7_of_12-np {
   width: 58.33%;
}

.span_6_of_12-np {
   width: 50%;
}

.span_5_of_12-np {
   width: 41.66%;
}

.span_4_of_12-np {
   width: 33.33%;
}

.span_3_of_12-np {
   width: 25%;
}

.span_2_of_12-np {
   width: 16.66%;
}

.span_1_of_12-np {
   width: 8.333%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col-np {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }
    
    .span_1_of_12-np, .span_2_of_12-np, .span_3_of_12-np, .span_4_of_12-np, .span_5_of_12-np, .span_6_of_12-np, .span_7_of_12-np, .span_8_of_12-np, .span_9_of_12-np, .span_10_of_12-np, .span_11_of_12-np, .span_12_of_12-np {
 width: 100%; 
 }
}

/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
 clear: both;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin: 0% 0 0.5% 0.5%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }
/*  GRID OF TWELVE  */
.span_12_of_12 {
 width: 100%;
}

.span_11_of_12 {
   width: 91.62%;
}
.span_10_of_12 {
   width: 83.25%;
}

.span_9_of_12 {
   width: 74.87%;
}

.span_8_of_12 {
   width: 66.5%;
}

.span_7_of_12 {
   width: 58.12%;
}

.span_6_of_12 {
   width: 49.75%;
}

.span_5_of_12 {
   width: 41.37%;
}

.span_4_of_12 {
   width: 33%;
}

.span_3_of_12 {
   width: 24.62%;
}

.span_2_of_12 {
   width: 16.25%;
}

.span_1_of_12 {
   width: 7.875%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }
    
    .span_1_of_12, .span_2_of_12, .span_3_of_12, .span_4_of_12, .span_5_of_12, .span_6_of_12, .span_7_of_12, .span_8_of_12, .span_9_of_12, .span_10_of_12, .span_11_of_12, .span_12_of_12 {
 width: 100%; 
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>XXX |  </title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
<meta name="Description" content="">
<meta name="Keywords" content="">
<meta property="og:title" content="">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="">
<meta property="og:url" content="">
<meta property="og:description" content="">
<meta property  ="fb:app_id" content="">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="" />

<link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.3/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="grid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="no-sp-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="color.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Neuton:400,200,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>

<body>
 <br> 
 <div class="container-page-80">
  <div class="section group">
   <div class="col span_2_of_12 height-40px">
    <img src="xdfd" class="main-logo" />
   </div>
   <div class="col span_6_of_12 height-40px">
    <input type="text" class="search-bar sanserif thin" placeholder="Search for items you are looking for..." >
   </div>
   <div class="col span_1_of_12 height-40px text-right">
    <button class="sign-in">Sign In</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col span_1_of_12 height-40px text-right">
    <button class="sign-in">Register</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col span_2_of_12 height-40px text-right">
   <button class="start-selling">START SELLING</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="page-container-100">
  <div class="section group">
   <div class="col span_12_of_12 height-75 puma">
    <div class="section-np group-np">
     <div class="col-np span_8_of_12-np">x
     </div>
     <div class="col-np span_4_of_12-np">
      <div class="section-np group-np">
       <div class="col-np span_12_of_12-np">y
       </div>
       <div class="col-np span_12_of_12-np">z
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

---

I am trying to adjust the height of "z" so that it is exactly 50% of the way down from the red box... I have tried everything in regards to adjusting heights and positions. When I change position to absolute it creates a mess. I tried doing adjustments with regards to pixels and percents and nothing is working. I know it has something to do with the parent class, but I do not understand this structuring.

Also, any tips in regards to proper code principles would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand, what's wrong with `position: absolute`?

```css
/* text types */
h1{font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; font-size: 24px; line-height: 125%;}
h2{font-family: 'Neuton', serif; margin: 5px 0px 10px 0px; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 200; line-height: 120%;}
h3{font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; margin: 8px 0px 2px 0px; font-size: 16px; line-height: 130%; font-weight: 600;}
h4{font-family: 'Neuton', serif; font-size: 16px; margin: 2px 0px 6px 0px; line-height: 120%; font-weight: 200;}
h5{font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; font-size: 12px;}
h6{font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;}

/* links */
a, a:hover, a:visited, a:active{text-decoration: none; outline: none; color: inherit;}
a.underline:hover{text-decoration: underline; color: inherit;}
a.readMore{font-family: 'Raleway', serif; font-size: 15px; margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px; font-weight: 700; color: #428bca;}
.thinner{
 font-weight: 200;
}
.thin{
 font-weight: 300;
}
.normal{
 font-weight: 400;
}
.bold{
 font-weight: 500;
}
.bolder{
 font-weight: 600;
}
.boldest{
 font-weight: 700;
}

.sanserif{
 font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

/* align */
.text-left{
 text-align: left;
}
.text-right{
 text-align: right;
}

/* body */
body, html{
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
.container-page-80{
 width: 80%;
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
}
.container-page-100{
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
}


/* height adj */
.height-100{
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
}
.height-75{
 height: 75%;
 position: absolute;
}
.height-50{
 height: 50%;
 position: absolute;
}
.height-40px{
 height: 40px;
}

/* positions */
.fixed{
 position: fixed;
}
.vert-align-1{
 vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

/* images */
img.main-logo{
 height: 35px;
}

/* inputs */
input[type=text].search-bar{
 outline: none;
 height: 28px;
 padding: 0px 6px;
 width: 93%;
 outline: none;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
 font-size: 15px;
 letter-spacing: 0.5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 opacity: .8;
 -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 -ms-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 transition: all 250ms ease-out;
}
input[type=text].search-bar:focus{
 color: black;
 opacity: 1;
}
input[type=text].search-bar:hover{
 color: black;
 opacity: 1;
}
button.start-selling{
 height: 30px;
 outline: none;
 background: none;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 font-size: 12px;
 color: white;
 padding: 0px 12px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 background-color: #9059b2;
 opacity: .9;
 -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 -ms-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 transition: all 250ms ease-out;
}
button.start-selling:hover{
 opacity: 1;
}
button.sign-in{
 height: 30px;
 outline: none;
 background: none;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 font-size: 12px;
 color: black;
 font-weight: 700;
 padding: 0px 12px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 background-color: none;
 opacity: .9;
 -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 -ms-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 transition: all 250ms ease-out;
}
.puma{
 background-color: red;
}






/*  SECTIONS  */
.section-np{
 clear: both;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col-np {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin: 0% 0 0% 0%;
}
.col-np:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group-np:before,
.group-np:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group-np:after { clear:both;}
.group-np { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }
/*  GRID OF TWELVE  */
.span_12_of_12-np {
 width: 100%;
}

.span_11_of_12-np {
   width: 91.66%;
}
.span_10_of_12-np {
   width: 83.33%;
}

.span_9_of_12-np {
   width: 75%;
}

.span_8_of_12-np {
   width: 66.66%;
}

.span_7_of_12-np {
   width: 58.33%;
}

.span_6_of_12-np {
   width: 50%;
}

.span_5_of_12-np {
   width: 41.66%;
}

.span_4_of_12-np {
   width: 33.33%;
}

.span_3_of_12-np {
   width: 25%;
}

.span_2_of_12-np {
   width: 16.66%;
}

.span_1_of_12-np {
   width: 8.333%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col-np {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }
    
    .span_1_of_12-np, .span_2_of_12-np, .span_3_of_12-np, .span_4_of_12-np, .span_5_of_12-np, .span_6_of_12-np, .span_7_of_12-np, .span_8_of_12-np, .span_9_of_12-np, .span_10_of_12-np, .span_11_of_12-np, .span_12_of_12-np {
 width: 100%; 
 }
}

/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
 clear: both;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin: 0% 0 0.5% 0.5%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }
/*  GRID OF TWELVE  */
.span_12_of_12 {
 width: 100%;
}

.span_11_of_12 {
   width: 91.62%;
}
.span_10_of_12 {
   width: 83.25%;
}

.span_9_of_12 {
   width: 74.87%;
}

.span_8_of_12 {
   width: 66.5%;
}

.span_7_of_12 {
   width: 58.12%;
}

.span_6_of_12 {
   width: 49.75%;
}

.span_5_of_12 {
   width: 41.37%;
}

.span_4_of_12 {
   width: 33%;
}

.span_3_of_12 {
   width: 24.62%;
}

.span_2_of_12 {
   width: 16.25%;
}

.span_1_of_12 {
   width: 7.875%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }
    
    .span_1_of_12, .span_2_of_12, .span_3_of_12, .span_4_of_12, .span_5_of_12, .span_6_of_12, .span_7_of_12, .span_8_of_12, .span_9_of_12, .span_10_of_12, .span_11_of_12, .span_12_of_12 {
 width: 100%; 
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>XXX |  </title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
<meta name="Description" content="">
<meta name="Keywords" content="">
<meta property="og:title" content="">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="">
<meta property="og:url" content="">
<meta property="og:description" content="">
<meta property  ="fb:app_id" content="">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="" />

<link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.3/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="grid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="no-sp-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="color.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Neuton:400,200,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>

<body>
 <br> 
 <div class="container-page-80">
  <div class="section group">
   <div class="col span_2_of_12 height-40px">
    <img src="xdfd" class="main-logo" />
   </div>
   <div class="col span_6_of_12 height-40px">
    <input type="text" class="search-bar sanserif thin" placeholder="Search for items you are looking for..." >
   </div>
   <div class="col span_1_of_12 height-40px text-right">
    <button class="sign-in">Sign In</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col span_1_of_12 height-40px text-right">
    <button class="sign-in">Register</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col span_2_of_12 height-40px text-right">
   <button class="start-selling">START SELLING</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="page-container-100">
  <div class="section group">
   <div class="col span_12_of_12 height-75 puma">
    <div class="section-np group-np">
     <div class="col-np span_8_of_12-np">x
     </div>
     <div class="col-np span_4_of_12-np">
      <div class="section-np group-np">
       <div class="col-np span_12_of_12-np">y
       </div>
       <div class="col-np span_12_of_12-np" style="position: absolute; top: 50%;">z
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```